# Error with linked server using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I started at this company, and the jobs were pretty complex and undocumented.
One of the procs checks on txtfiles that SSIS creates by using a linked server that uses Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and points to its own C drive. Using that, the job does a count on each table, and compares it to its totals. Maybe unnecessarily complex.

It was working properly till last Friday, when I started getting the error:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "textserver"
returned message "Unspecified error". Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
"Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "textserver".
```

The query used is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM textserver...[textfile#txt]
```

I've tried rebooting the server, and recreating the linked server to no avail.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Check this out: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36700

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems in the past, but restarting the linked to server usually worked for me. A few things to try:

1. You may also want to verify the account running the SSIS package has rights to the linked server location on the C drive.
2. Also, make sure remote transactions are allowed.
3. Last suggestion would be to see if any MS updates or patches were installed since it last worked and try rolling them back.